# Testing a page against webkit rendering engine in headless mode

Tags: javascript, django, webkit, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use django-wkhtmltopdf wrapper for wkhtmltopdf executable which uses webkit rendering engine to convert html pages to pdf. However I developed my pages wrt chrome/firefox, and they have dynamically generated data and javascript. Some of the javascript used is not being supported by webkit, and process dies silently. So, the pdf page that I get is incomplete and I cannot pinpoint where exactly the problem is. What can I do?

Note: I am developing in Windows and using Vagrant to run development environment on Ubuntu 15.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf has a  --debug-javascript option

Comment: @user993553: that will help. Would you like to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Plus, I realized a '<' character that I used in a javascript comment caused rest of the code to be considered as html (wkhtmltopdf keeps the intermediary html file in /tmp folder when pdf is not generated; when I opened that with nano editor, it highlighted rest of the code blue, like it did for other html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf has a --debug-javascript option.